# Openvpn: Set specific default gateway for one staticclient

Tags: openvpn

I would like to create a configuration in which one client is a default gateway for another one specific client.

I have an openvpn server configured in client-to-client mode.Two clients are configiured as follows:

```
cd /etc/openvpn/staticclients

root@host:/etc/openvpn/staticclients# cat test1
ifconfig-push 10.7.0.10 255.255.255.255
root@host:/etc/openvpn/staticclients# cat test2
ifconfig-push 10.7.0.5 255.255.255.255
```

How could i set default gateway for test1 client to move all traffic via test2 client? So after connecting to vpn test1 default gateway would be via test2. Is such configuration possible via some push route?

Thanks for help and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to `push "route-gateway 10.7.0.5"` in the configuration of the first client.

Also note that by default OpenVPN servers do not allows the clients to "see" each other, so you might need to enable `--client-to-client`.

(You also might need to set up a proper `iroute` entry to achieve what you need, I dunno.)